# Return using AJAX a text into a specified div?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In a form on `index.php` I post using AJAX to the `submit.php` file. Everything is working ok but I want to return in a special div in `index.php` with id `#remaining` a text like below.

How do I tell `submit.php` that this one message must be placed in the `<div id="remaining"></div>` of `index.php` ?

```
if($rem_posts<1)
{
echo "No credits, please buy credits";
}
else
{
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [$.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.

```
$('#remaining').load('submit.php');
```

Comment: How to replace the text each time instead of writing it next to each other?

Comment: I don't understand so much. You mean the text in `#remaining` ? If so with $.load any time you call the ajax request it update the text in `#remaining` with the text result in submit.php

Answer (score 1):

There is no context in your question. The easiest way to load into a div is like so:

```
$('#remaining').load('submit.php');
```

Comment: Nice, but how do I replace the returned text each time ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have the submit.php file echo a JSON response and use the [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) success callback to place it in the appropriate location like this:

```
// PHP //
<?php
    echo '{"remaining" : "No credits, please but credits", "foo" : "bar", "bar" : "foo"}';
?>

// JavaScript //
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            $('#remaining').text(data.remaining); // Add Specific Message
            $('#foo').text(data.bar); // Some Other Info
            $('#bar').text(data.foo); // Additional Info
        }
});
</script>
```

I hope it helps!